# Reduce a Caffe network model

Tags: c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'd like to use Caffe to extract image features. However, it takes too long to process an image, so I'm looking for ways to optimize for speed.

One thing I noticed is that the network definition I'm using has four extra layers on top the one from which I'm reading a result (and there are no feedback signals, so they should be safe to delete).

I tried to delete them from the definition file but it had no effect at all. I guess I might need to remove the corresponding part of the file that contains pre-trained weights, too. That is, however, a binary file (a protobuffer) so editing it is not that easy.

Do you think that removing the four layers might have a profound effect of the net performance?

If so then how do I get familiar with the file contents so that I could edit it and how do I know which parts to remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, I don't think removing the binary weights will have any effect.
Second, you can do it easily using the python interface: see [this tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb).
Last but not least, have you tried running [`caffe time`](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/interfaces.html) to measure the performance of your net? this may help you identify the bottlenecks of your computations.

PS,
You might find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30822009/1714410) relevant as well.

Answer (score 1):

Caffemodel stores data as key-value pair. Caffe only copies weight for those layers (in train.prototxt) having exactly same name as caffemodel. Hence I don't think removing binary weights will work. If you want to change network structure, just modify train.prototxt and deploy.txt.

If you insist to remove weights from binary file, follow this [caffe example](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb).

And to make sure you delete right part, this [visualizing tool](http://ethereon.github.io/netscope/#/editor) should help.

Answer (score 0):

I would retrain on a smaller input size, change strides, etc. However if you want to reduce file size, I'd suggest quantizing the weights https://github.com/yuanyuanli85/CaffeModelCompression and then using something like lzma compression (xz for unix). We do this so we can deploy to mobile devices. 8 bit weights compress nicely.