# How to get features from several layers using c++ in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

How can I get both the 4096 dim feature layer and the 1000 dim class layer in caffe after one forward pass using C++?

I tried to look it up in `extract_features.cpp` but it uses some weird `datum` object, so I cannot really understand how it works.

So far I was simply cropping my `prototxt` files up to the layer that I wanted to extract and used

```
[...]
net->ForwardPrefilled();
Blob<float> *output_layer = net->output_blobs()[0];
const float *begin = output_layer->cpu_data();
const float *end = begin + output_layer->channels();
return vector<float>(begin, end);
```

but that does not work if I want to extract two specific layers (eg "prob" and "fc7") simultaneously.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use C++. Extracting features from different layers is much simpler in python.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. (On python it is already working.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

The simple work flow of `extract_feature.cpp`(suppose you have a `shared_ptr<Net<float> > net` object in c++):

1. perform net forward to process input: `net->Forward()`.
   In this step, there is a `Data` layer in the `net` to read the input images. So if in your own app/code you want read an image to `cv::Mat image` and feed it into `net`, you can write a code like:

   ```
   // for data preprocess
   shared_ptr<caffe::DataTransformer<float> > data_transformer;
   caffe::TransformationParameter trans_para;
   // set mean
   trans_para.set_mean_file("/path/to/image_mean.binaryproto");
   // set crop size, e.g.here is cropping 227x227
   trans_para.set_crop_size(227);
   // instantiate a DataTransformer using trans_para for image preprocess
   data_transformer.reset(new caffe::DataTransformer<float>(trans_para, caffe::TEST));
   const std::vector<caffe::Blob<float> *> net_input = net->input_blobs();
   // maybe you need to resize image before this step
   data_transformer->Transform(image, *net_input[0]);
   net->Forward();
   ```

   And the `net.prototxt` should have a `Input` layer as the first layer, e.g. this [deploy.prototxt](https://gist.github.com/knsong/5bf712fba1716bf69d84ffc747998f3c).
2. get the feature blobs according to their names:`const boost::shared_ptr<Blob<Dtype> > feature_blob = net->blob_by_name(blob_names[i])`
3. extract the feature data from the blob you get into a structure you want, e.g. an arry, a simple sample code can be:

   ```
   count = feature_blob->channels() * feature_blob->height() * 
       feature_blob->width();
   float* feature_array = new float[count]; 
   const float* feature_blob_data = feature_blob->cpu_data() +
       feature_blob->offset(n); // feature data generated from 
                                // the nth input image within a batch 
   memcpy(feature_array, feature_blob_data, count * sizeof(float)); 
   ...// other operations
   delete [] feature_array;
   ```

Note that the data stored from `feature_blob_data` is in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).

---

The `extract_feature.cpp`'s usage should be like this for your task:

```
path/to/extract_features your_pretrained_model.caffemodel \
    net.prototxt 4096_dim_feature_blob_name,1000_dim_class_feature_blob_name \
    saved_4096_dim_feature_database,saved_1000_dim_class_feature_database \
    num_mini_batches(times for forward pass) lmdb(or leveldb) GPU(or CPU)
```

The `net.prototxt` should contain a data layer that can read the input image data.

And when running, it will first the read image data from the data layer within `net.prototxt` and perform `num_mini_batches` times of forward pass and extract the 2 two feature blob `4096_dim_feature_blob_name`, `1000_dim_class_feature_blob_name`'s data into a structure typed of `Datum` and then serialize them to save in the database `saved_4096_dim_feature_database`, `saved_1000_dim_class_feature_database` which are typed of `lmdb` or `leveldb`.

When finished, you can read the saved feature data from `saved_4096_dim_feature_database`, `saved_1000_dim_class_feature_database` using a data layer in `net.prototxt` respectively.

BTW, `datum` is a structure that can store at most 4D data as well as the data's shape and label information etc. It is defined in `caffe.proto`, generated using [google protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf) and is convenient for data interchange between caffe and database like `LMDB` and `LEVELDB`.

Comment: The problem is that I would need an extract of the code of `extract_features.cpp` and insert it into my c++ code. As I'm not able to understand the code of `extract_features.cpp` yet, I thought I would ask if someone has a minimal working example ( no batches, no lmdb output -> just inputting an image and storing the output feature vector in an array or  cv::mat file.

Comment: @mcExchange I've update my answer for this. Please see it.

Comment: @mcExchange Also this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/39766758/6281477 may help you find out how to read an image to cv::Mat and feed it into a caffe `Net` object.

Comment: Does `extract_features.cpp` exist now? I cannot find it anymore (Caffe 1.0).